# Php Arrays with vertical tab content

Tags: php, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to **Hide** One of my side navigation buttons if not content is loaded

*(Each section varies from 1-4 tabs per section of the body part and currently have three tabs loaded)*

I am using a PHP Array to load all my content for this section of the webpage.

Here is an example of some of my code (stripped down much as I could)
[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimerbox/Rw6j2/9/)

My first thought is to do and "if" and "else" statement which I've tried from another example from here but I still need to figure out a way to turn off the css for the button just not really sure how to tackle that!

Any help is appreciated and please note I'm newbie to php!

Also here is a link of how the section content loads with the array just to help visually:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTeYp.jpg
[image: Screenshot of Array Content]

Here is a snippet of my array that's being included into the php file

```
// #Hips#
$injuries['Hips'] = array(
    "BodyPartLink" => "Hips",
    "TitlePage" => "Hips Injuries & Education",
    "IntroTxt" => "Hips Intro Text Here",
    "SectionTab1" => "",
    "SectionTab2" => "Hip Condition #2",
    "SectionTab3" => "Hip Condition #3",
    "ContentSection" => "Hips Dummy Text Here For Large Text Section"
);

// #Hips  Section Contents TAB 1 #
$Tab1SectionContents['Hips'] = array(
    "Definition" => "<span class='edu-sub-category-txt-bold'>Definition:</span>Lower Back Information coming soon! ",
    "Function" => "<span class='edu-sub-category-txt-bold'>Function:</span>Information coming soon!",
    "Mechanism" => "Mechanism of Injury ",
    "MechanismTxt" => "Information coming soon!",
    "Sign-Symptoms" => "Signs & Symptoms ",
    "Sign-SymptomsTxt" => "Information coming soon!",
    "Etiology" => "Etiology ",
    "EtiologyTxt" => "Information coming soon!",
    "Pero-Treatment" => "Pero Treatment ",
    "Pero-TreatmentTxt" => "Information coming soon!",
    "Other-Treatment" => "Other Treatment ",
    "Other-TreatmentTxt" => "Information coming soon!"
);

// #Hips  Section Contents TAB 2 #
$Tab2SectionContents['Hips'] = array(
    "Definition" => "<span class='edu-sub-category-txt-bold'>Definition:</span>Lower Back -- Phasellus erat sem, molestie vitae turpis et, vehicula facilisis dolor. Mauris ut iaculis eros,     in auctor nibh. In eget nisl tristique elit varius semper. ",
    "Function" => "<span class='edu-sub-category-txt-bold'>Function:</span> Function -- molestie vitae turpis et, vehicula facilisis dolor. Mauris ut iaculis eros,",
    "Mechanism" => "Mechanism of Injury ",
    "MechanismTxt" => "Text for Mechanism",
    "Sign-Symptoms" => "Signs & Symptoms ",
    "Sign-SymptomsTxt" => "Signs & Symptoms ",
    "Etiology" => "Etiology ",
    "EtiologyTxt" => "Etiology ",
    "Pero-Treatment" => "Pero Treatment ",
    "Pero-TreatmentTxt" => "Pero Treatment ",
    "Other-Treatment" => "Other Treatment ",
    "Other-TreatmentTxt" => "Other Treatment "
);

// #Hips  Section Contents TAB 3 #
$Tab3SectionContents['Hips'] = array(
    "Definition" => "<span class='edu-sub-category-txt-bold'>Definition:</span>Lower Back -- Phasellus erat sem, molestie vitae turpis et, vehicula facilisis dolor. Mauris ut iaculis eros,     in auctor nibh. In eget nisl tristique elit varius semper. ",
    "Function" => "<span class='edu-sub-category-txt-bold'>Function:</span> Function -- molestie vitae turpis et, vehicula facilisis dolor. Mauris ut iaculis eros,",
    "Mechanism" => "Mechanism of Injury ",
    "MechanismTxt" => "Text for Mechanism",
    "Sign-Symptoms" => "Signs & Symptoms ",
    "Sign-SymptomsTxt" => "Signs & Symptoms ",
    "Etiology" => "Etiology ",
    "EtiologyTxt" => "Etiology ",
    "Pero-Treatment" => "Pero Treatment ",
    "Pero-TreatmentTxt" => "Pero Treatment ",
    "Other-Treatment" => "Other Treatment ",
    "Other-TreatmentTxt" => "Other Treatment "
); // ## END HIPS ##
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do it with Javascript. Check if the `div` associated with your tab is empty - hence no data/content came through for it. If it is empty, remove it.

```
$(function(){
    if (!$('.element').html()){
        // If the element is empty, remove it
        $('.element').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please mark my question as correct if it works for you (and +1 it). Thanks =)

Comment: Oh ok once I get a chance I will for sure do that! Thanks still pretty new to this site! :)

Comment: No luck with the js it shuts off the entire area of the tabs I think I need to rethink this! I'm thinking I need to do a foreach loop for the tab sections of each area so if it does not need it it will generate the tabs to begin with but thanks for trying!!

Comment: If your page is live, feel free to send me a link. jQuery approach should work. Just sounds like you're targeting all the tabs, not just the specific tab, which should have an id on it.